# how can i open wifi menu in status bar in mac using objective c

Tags: macos

I am trying to make a Mac application that opens wifi icon in the status bar when i click a button in my  application view. I'm wondering if this is something that cannot be worked around because of Apple security concerns. If anybody knows a way to get around this, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically you can do that with AppleScript but what's the purpose? The menu bar item is just a view, you can get almost every information from the CoreWLAN or other frameworks.

Comment: i need to implement that for connect or disconnect the network.Connect/ disconnect button launches the system’s Wi-Fi connection window.from that user can connect to a particular network.

Comment: how can I do that with AppleScript? I'm stuck on this

Comment: As you're creating a Cocoa application anyway. better use the `CoreWLAN` framework or `networksetup` or the executable of the `Apple80211` framework with `NSTask`. It's much more reliable and convenient than the ugly GUI scripting of AppleScript.

Comment: can I do that with CoreWLAN framework? I can fetch  network details from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a non-Mac-App-Store application, you can probably use the Accessibility APIs to find it and open it.  Otherwise, it probably isn't possible, and even then, it is likely nontrivial.